# when I import ts suffix files, Webpack HMR not work;

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I use the HMR as per the official [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/), when I import `.js` suffix files, it works very well. but when I import `.ts` suffix files, HMR not work;

I guess if `ts-loader` did something.

here is my config:

webpack.config.js :

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3031,
    hot: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

index.ts :

```js
import printMe from './test';
printMe();

if ((module as any).hot) {
  (module as any).hot.accept('./test', function () {
    console.log('Accepting the updated printMe module!');
    printMe();
  })
}
```

test.ts:

```js
export default function printMe() {
  const dom = document.createElement('div');
  dom.innerHTML = 'I get called from printMe';
  document.body.append(dom);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `ts-loader` doesn't support HMR. From their GitHub:

> We do not support HMR as we did not yet work out a reliable way how to set it up.

There's [a workaround](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/352#issuecomment-330842439) though! You can enable `transpileOnly: true` in `ts-loader`. Note that just by enabling `transpileOnly`, you'll lose some type checking features and should use [fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Realytics/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin) to get full type checking again.

See [Hot module replacement guide](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#hot-module-replacement) and [Docs for `transpileOnly`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#transpileonly) and [this example](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/master/examples/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem

```
  **resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },**
```

See: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configuration